# How can I select different values in one table?

Tags: sql, plsql

```
INST | MAXRATE | MAXDATE  | TAX |
--------------------------------
1    |   1.5   |  17      |  0  |     
2    |   0     |  20      |  0  |   
3    |   0     |  35      |  0  |   
4    |   0     |  45      |  18 |    
5    |   0     |  50      |  1  |
```

I have a table like this. And I want to select a maximum value in each row. For example, the first column has an INST and I want to pick the max value. And I also want to pick 50 as a MAXDATE. How can I pick these values? Here is an example output I want.

```
INST | MAXRATE | MAXDATE  | TAX |
---------------------------------
5    |   1.5   |  50      |  18 |
```

Comment: Then use the `MAX` aggregation function for each column.

Comment: But what if I want to pick 45 instead of 50 or 3?

Comment: Then you need to define the criteria according to which you want values.

Comment: You can use MAX function on each column.
eg: SELECT MAX(INST), MAX(MAXRATE), MAX(MAXDATE), MAX(TAX) FROM TableName

Comment: "But..." indicates you did not ask what you really wanted to know. Please pay more attention to ask the correct question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  INST NUMBER, MAXRATE NUMBER, MAXDATE NUMBER, TAX NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO t1 (INST, MAXRATE, MAXDATE, TAX) VALUES (1,  1.5, 17, 0);
INSERT INTO t1 (INST, MAXRATE, MAXDATE, TAX) VALUES (2,  0,   20, 0);
INSERT INTO t1 (INST, MAXRATE, MAXDATE, TAX) VALUES (3,  0,   35, 0);
INSERT INTO t1 (INST, MAXRATE, MAXDATE, TAX) VALUES (4,  0,   45, 18);
INSERT INTO t1 (INST, MAXRATE, MAXDATE, TAX) VALUES (5,  0,   50, 1);

SELECT MAX(INST), MAX(MAXRATE), MAX(MAXDATE), MAX(TAX) FROM t1;
```

https://sqlize.online/sql/oracle21/d281b1d5c7e91c8779773733c4f4273e/

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this idea or something similar?

```
SELECT MAX(INST) max_inst, b.max_maxrate
FROM YourTable a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT inst, MAX(maxrate) max_maxrate
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY inst
) b 
ON a.inst = b.inst AND a.maxrate = b.maxrate
```